# Is it possible to setup background color on hackmd?

Tags: hackmd

I usually use hackmd for personal note about shell script & yaml code. But the hackmd's default code block background is gray. Sometimes the gray background color is hard to view. Thus, is there any way to setup background color and font color? If so, please provide the example and appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

After googling and verification for a while time, I use following simple code to change code block background color. Post in here for reference.

```
<style>

.markdown-body pre, code{
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Much appreciated! I made an open [HackMD](https://hackmd.io/@openguide/hackmd/) guide. This will help me get started with learning how to customize .md files using CSS now that I know I need the `style` tags.